# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of symmetric matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I am trying , without success , **to prove that DE is a symmetric** matrix according to the statements below :

```
D and E are Symmetric matrices 2x2.
v1  = 1/√2 [1]  , v1 is an eigenvector of D with eigenvalue = λ1
           [1]

v1 is also eigenvector of E with eigenvalue =  µ1

λ1 and µ1 not necessarily equals
```

I would appriciate you help here.

Comment: Show your attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both D and E are symmetric 2x2 matrices
$$
\text{D}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{$d_0$} & \text{$d_a$} \\
 \text{$d_a$} & \text{$d_1$} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\text{E}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{$e_0$} & \text{$e_a$} \\
 \text{$e_a$} & \text{$e_1$} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$DE$ is symmetric if and only if $(DE)^T=DE$ or:
$$
d_a e_1 + d_0 e_a=d_a e_0 + d_1 e_a \iff \frac{d_1-d_0}{d_a}=\frac{e_1-e_0}{e_a}
$$
then let's see what the Eigen Value equation implies:
$$
D\binom{1}{1}=\lambda\binom{1}{1} \iff \begin{cases}d_0+d_a=\lambda\\d_a+d_1=\lambda\end{cases} \implies d_0-d_1=0 
$$
exactly the same argument applies to $E$ so
$$
e_0-e_1=0 
$$
so by substitution the condition for $DE$ to be symmetric becomes:
$$
\frac{d_1-d_0}{d_a}=\frac{e_1-e_0}{e_a} \iff \frac{0}{d_a}=\frac{0}{e_a}\iff 0=0 \rm{\,\,\,\,\,which\,\, is\,\, true}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! , Is there any chance that you can explain how did you get to the equation below the statement (DE)T = DE (one line below)?

Comment: calculate explicitly the matrix product and equate it element by element to it's transpose, you will get 4 equations of which two are always satisfied (those coming from the diagonal) and the other two are identical leading only to the equation i've written

Comment: Oh now I got it , Thank you!!